# Change time of a single cell in CSV using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a .CSV file and i need to modify a single cell by changing only the **Time** format of the last row.

`Import-Csv .\logs.csv | select -Last 1`

will output the last row

```
Date       : 2019-07-31 02:15 GMT
ID         : 1252321
```

I need to modify the *time* from the *date* column from **GMT** to **GMT+8** (military format) on the same .csv file.

Expected Result would be

```
2019-07-31 10:15:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially do something like the following, which relies on the `ConvertTime` method in the `TimezoneInfo` class. I chose `W. Australia Standard Time` as the UTC+8 time zone. You can choose something more appropriate. The `[-1]` index grabs the last row of the CSV contents `$csv`.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\logs.csv
$csv[-1].date = Get-Date ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime([datetime]($csv[-1].date),([System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById('W. Australia Standard Time')))) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm "GMT"+8'
$csv | Export-Csv .\logs.csv -NoType
```

You can remove the `GMT+8` part if you feel it is not necessary. An easier alternative is to just add X number of hours based on your current system's time zone to the selected time. If you are already in GMT, you can just add 8 hours.

```
Get-Date [datetime]($csv[-1].date).AddHours(8) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
```